# Uploading xcode project to app store

Tags: objective-c, xcode, upload

I’ve been going around in circles. Any help will be appreciated.

I have submitted all the application details to iTunes connect - Thats not a problem.

As I went to upload my binary version I got a message telling me this is no longer possible and it needs to be uploaded through xcode?

I’ve searched all over and am unable to find where.

Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upload application, using Application Loader, which is available with modern versions of xCode, or can be separately downloaded from iTunes Connect.

Comment: Don't forget setting up and building for release with your distribution prov. profile and certificates, otherwise you'll get a bad binary rejection notice from the App Store once you submit.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the `Window > Organizer`

You also need to `Build > Build and Archive` it to show up in the list there.

You also must have installed the necessary certificates to sign the app and sign the installer. Read carefully the docs about *Submitting to the Mac App Store* available on the developer portal.

You know https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action